# Solution to a coding problem available on codeforces the link is below it is called Presents problem -136A

Tags: c++

This is the coding solution to a coding problem :
https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/136/A
i am unable to understand how this came as a solution if anyone could help me with that.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int a[110];
int main() {
    int n,e;
    cin>>n;
    int x[n+10];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin>>x[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        a[x[i]]=i+1;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int x[n+10];` This is not valid C++.  Then `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is not a standard C++ header.  Better you learn C++ from good books than online competition coding websites.

Comment: You need to include the statement of the problem as text in the question body.

Answer (score 0):

The input array in this represents who the person at position `i` gave the gift to

The output represents who the person received the gift from.

so if `x[i]` represents the person who person i gave the gift two then that means that person `x[i]` received the gift from person `i` (you can see that he assigns the value of `i + 1` but that is only because `i` are 0 based while the actual friend number are 1-base)

so the line `a[x[i]] = i + 1` means person `x[i]` received a gift from person `i + 1`